# return a js object with all of a second object's properties stripped out

Tags: javascript

What's an efficient *non-destructive* javascript (jquery ok if needed) way to return everything in object A that isn't in object B, as well as ABSOLUTELY NOTHING from object B? e.g.

**Object A**

```
objectA = {
    thing1 : {/*various sub-properties*/},
    thing2 : {/*various sub-properties*/},
    thing3 : {/*various sub-properties*/},
    thing4 : {/*various sub-properties*/}
}
```

**Object B**

```
objectB = {
    thing3 : {/*various sub-properties*/},
    thing4 : {/*various sub-properties*/},
    thing5 : {/*various sub-properties*/}
}
```

Should return

```
{
    thing1 = {/*various sub-properties*/},
    thing2 = {/*various sub-properties*/}
}
```

In my case, the values of the sub-properties may be different. It's stripping by the identifier that matters.

Comment: Simply `for (var prop in objectB) delete objectA[prop];`?

Comment: ah, sounds sensible, although it'd need to be on cloned objects so as not to destroy the original objects

Comment: Maybe you should specify this in your description. I would have said the same than Bergi.

Comment: edited to say non-destructive now, good point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a simple loop will do it:

```
var returnObject = {};

for (var prop in objectA) {
    if (objectA.hasOwnProperty(prop) && !objectB.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        returnObject[prop] = objectA[prop];
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GWXR3/

If you can use the underscore library there is the [omit](http://underscorejs.org/#omit) method which would work nicely (along with the keys method):

```
var returnObject = _.omit(objectA, _.keys(objectB));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GWXR3/1/

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
function check(a, b) {
  var out = {};
  for (var key in a) {
    if (a.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      if (b[key]) { continue; }
      out[key] = a[key];
    }
  }
  return out;
}
```